# How do I validate the RSS feed link?

Tags: 7, forms

This is my custom form with three fields,

Image :

[image]

CODE :

```
function planet_extension_form($form,&$form_submit){
$form['url']=array(
'#title' => 'URL',
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => TRUE,
'#size' => 35,
'#description' => t('Enter the URL'),
'#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('www.example.com')),
);
$form['title']=array(
'#title' => 'Title',
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => TRUE,
'#size' => 35,
'#description' => t('Enter the Title'),
'#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('Title'))
);
$form['email']=array(
'#title' => 'email',
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => TRUE,
'#size' => 35,
'#description' => t('Enter you valid email'),
'#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('example@example.com'))
);
$form['submit']=array(
'#type' =>'submit',
'#value' => 'Submit',
);

return $form;
}


//email validation
function planet_extension_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!valid_email_address($form_state['values']['email'])) {
    form_set_error('email', t('That e-mail address is not valid.'));
  }
}
```

Just like email validation I want to validate the if the link submitted is RSS feed link, in my custom module.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try using file_get_contents for url/rss.xml ? I think this will work in the validation. I don see any way in drupal to check this, only PHP way of doing can help you I guess.